# Make Module to also work with Mobile Theme

Tags: mobile, module, prestashop

I want my built module to be loaded in Mobile Theme also.
My module is working properly on Full theme.
How Can I get the hook my module to the Mobile theme?

I tried public function hookMobileHeader($params), but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your hook in index.tpl in your mobile folder in your theme
example {hook h="hook_of_your_module"} for hookMobileHeader you can assign your js and css files for your module.